# Nodemailer google cloud function error code: 304

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have a firebase google cloud function that sends an email via javascript with **cors** and **nodemailer.**

I am getting an **error code: 304** in some occasions with different destination emails.
Why would this be happening occasionally and only when I change the email destination. Sometimes its works and sometimes it doesnt.

How can the condition be sometimes false by changing the email send to destination? Do i need to set the cache somehow in the function?

- Allow Un-secure apps is enabled followed by Captcha Unlocked

**error code: 304**

> notModified   - The conditional request would have been successful, but
> the condition was false, so no body was sent.

[image]

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});


// Gmail configuration to Send eMail
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'email',
        pass: 'passwors'
    }
});



exports.sendMailPasswordReset = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    cors(req, res, () => {


    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'team <team@example.app>', // Something like: Jane Doe <janedoe@gmail.com>
        to: 'example@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Password Reset', // email subject
        html: `html body` // email content in HTML
    };

    // returning result
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
        if(erro){
            return res.send(erro.toString());
        }
        return res.send('true');
});
});
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to allow "less secure apps" in your Google security settings? https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I have done this and followed it with the captcha unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send back a constant value.

```
return res.send('true');
```

**Error code 304:** Is returning false because it is always returning the same constant.

To fix the problem the send value needs to be different every time.

For Example:

```
let random = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
return res.send('true_' + random);
```

I also added for cors

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
```

Here is a detailed understanding of [Error code 304](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1)